# What is the right way to store a path relative to My Documents

Tags: windows, winapi

I need to write code to handle the following scenario:

1. Prompt the user for a path to a file.
2. The user may enter a path that is beneath her "My Documents" folder.  The path might also be to a location unrelated to her "My Documents" folder.
3. Store the path for later lookup.
4. Sometime later, read the stored path to her file and load her file.
5. Many months later, the user decides to relocate her "My Documents" folder.  Windows provides a way to do this.  She naturally expects my application to continue functioning normally.

The code in step 4 should still work.  There should be a clever way to remember whether the path is a normal path or relative to My Documents and fetch the file accordingly.

Does the Windows API have this functionality build-in?

What is the right way to do this?

Also, is there any kind of special syntax the user can enter when typing the path so that the Windows API can automatically reference the location relative to My Documents?

Comment: [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) returns the current location. How you store information that decides, whether or not the data designates a *"normal"* path or a relative path, is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx) or 
[`SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) to get the path to the Documents folder, then check if the user's input starts with that path, and if so then use [`PathRelativePathTo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773740.aspx) to create a relative path from it.  Later, you can retrieve the current Documents folder path again and use [`PathCombine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773571(v=vs.85).aspx) to append the relative path to it.

Comment: `SHGetFolderPath` is deprecated, even if it still works... I'd not recommend using it :-)

Comment: @Jcl that's why I also mentioned the `KNOWNFOLDERID` equivalent. The OP did not say which version of Windows was being used. The `KNOWNFOLDERID` API does not exist on XP, which is still a popular version to use/code for, even if Microsoft does not support it anymore. `CSIDL` can be used in XP and earlier, `KNOWNFOLDERID` can be used on Vista and later.

Answer (score 0):

In the API, there's [ShGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28VS.85%29.aspx), using a [KNOWNFOLDERID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx) of `FOLDERID_Documents`.

Depending on what you are coding on, there might be predefined functions for it. For example, in .NET, you could use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` (links to MSDN for [GetFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.100).aspx))

So if you store a relative path to `My Documents` as the filename, you can always create an absolute path using those functions.

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question.  It turns out, programmatic tricks are unnecessary.

See also:
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), 
[sevenforums](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/278047-invalid-junction-after-moving-my-documents.html)

I discovered the root cause of the problem.  The "My Documents" junction was not pointing to the new location.  I expected Windows7 to automatically change the "My Documents" junction to the new location, but it did not.  I was able to fix the problem by running the following bit of cmd code at the command line.

```
:: Run this as admin

:: Delete the wrong junction which points to "C:\Users\{username}\Documents"
rmdir "My Documents"

:: Create a new junction to the new My Documents folder
mklink  /J  "My Documents"  "D:\MyData\Documents"

:: Change the attributes of the junction, not the folder it points to
attrib  +H  +S  +I  "My Documents"  /L

icacls "My Documents" /setowner SYSTEM  /L
icacls "My Documents" /deny Everyone:(RD)  /L
```

The right way to store the path is just:
"C:\Users{username}\My Documents..."

If this does not work, it is probably caused by an incorrect junction created by Windows7.  The Junction can be fixed with the cmd code above.

Comment: This does not answer the question that the asker asked. -1